# Finding the indexes of an element of 9x9 array that is divided into nine 3x3 arrays

Tags: c

In order to create an ultimate tic-tac-toe game, which includes a 9x9 array that is divided into nine 3x3 sub-arrays.

Each sub-array is numbered in the following manner:

[image]

And I want to create a function that if the user for example enters two parameters, it goes to the cell in the 9x9 matrix, (or gives back the indexes).

For example, if I enter 2,2: I go to the second 3x3 matrix, and there I go to the second cell, which means I end up in cell [0,4] in the 9x9 matrix.

I'm writing the code in the C language.
All I ended up with is making a big function with many loops that takes me directly to the wanted cell, but its too much I think, I would be happy for a simpler way to do that.

Any ideas?

The following code is just the start of what I did.
I divided the 9x9 matrix into three columns, and each time I deal with a column according to the number from 1-9 the user chosen for sub array, and from there I go to a series of functions for each sub array to find the proper place. It’s too complicated and long, and that’s the problem of my code. That’s why I’m searching for an alternative.

```
int Insert_Move(char player, char GameBoard[Lines][Columns], int chosen_pos,
                int next_subboard)

{
    if(next_subboard == 3 || next_subboard == 6 || next_subboard == 9)
        return First_Column_9x9(player, GameBoard, chosen_pos, next_subboard);

    if(next_subboard == 2 || next_subboard == 5 || next_subboard == 8)
        return  Second_Column_9x9(player, GameBoard, chosen_pos, next_subboard);

    if(next_subboard == 1 || next_subboard == 4 || next_subboard == 7)
        return Third_Column_9x9(player, GameBoard, chosen_pos, next_subboard);

    return 1; /* Success */
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and point out where you are running into problems.

Comment: a) show us what you did so far
b)not a C expert but i think:
 use an 3x3 array of objects and each object is a 3x3array
 then i think you can access a 2dimension array as a vector, so by giving 2,2 you can get the second (3x3 array) object and with the second number (2) you will get the actual cell

Comment: I did. Im searching for a smipler algorithm thats is just mathematics, but can't get a grip of the right formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the two-dimensional array as:

X coordinate = ((p1-1)℅3)*3 + (p2-1)℅3;

Y coordinate = ((p1-1)/3)*3 + (p2-1)/3;

Comment: I checked 6,5 for example, I should get X=4, Y=7, but its not working

Comment: Please also send it's output

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that takes an array of two `size_t` values to store the indices of the cell, and the two position arguments given by the user. It finds the indices for the given positions in a zero-indexed 3X3 array, and then combines these results to produce the indices in the 9X9 array.

I put it in a little program to test a couple of inputs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void get_index(size_t indices[2], int pos, int sub_board);

int main(void)
{
    size_t indices[2];
    int pos, sub_board;

    pos = 2;
    sub_board = 2;

    get_index(indices, pos, sub_board);

    printf("Cell indices are: [%zu][%zu]\n", indices[0], indices[1]);

    pos = 6;
    sub_board = 9;

    get_index(indices, pos, sub_board);

    printf("Cell indices are: [%zu][%zu]\n", indices[0], indices[1]);    

    return 0;
}

void get_index(size_t indices[2], int pos, int sub_board)
{
    size_t row_pos, col_pos;
    size_t row_sub, col_sub;

    row_pos = (pos - 1) / 3;
    col_pos = (pos - 1) % 3;
    row_sub = (sub_board - 1) / 3;
    col_sub = (sub_board - 1) % 3;

    indices[0] = 3 * row_sub + row_pos;    
    indices[1] = 3 * col_sub + col_pos;

}
```

Output:

```
Cell indices are: [0][4]
Cell indices are: [7][8]
```